# Handling computer files in simulation-based research with multiple storage drives

Tags: data, code, workflow, backup-archiving, document-organization

Can somebody give me an advice about how to efficiently handle data files, source codes, documents, and manuscripts of research projects based on numerical simulations? My problem is that I use multiple computers while the maily-used one has limited storage space, and that the files and directories tend to scatter over multiple storage devices without being synchronized if I don't take much effort of manually deciding which ones should be stored where and remembering the decisions. If there are some people under similar situation described below as me, I wonder if they could share their detailed know-hows.

I work on simulation-based research using multiple computing environments (a laptop computer, desktop computers at work and home, as well as computing clusters at work) to write program codes, run the jobs, analyze the output data and make figures, and write manuscripts. The OS is exclusively Linux so far. I don't have a stable job, and I need to move from one place to the next every now and then.

Most of my human time is spent on my laptop by writing codes and making plots from the output files of simulations. However, this laptop has a limited amount of storage space (about 500 GB). Sometimes one project generates 100 GB or more output data in total before publishing a manuscript, and I work on multiple projects in parallel. I often look at my old source codes, analysis scripts, and examine output data files of finished or frozen projects. Therefore, it would be the most convenient if I could collect all the files related to all the current and past projects on the laptop, but this is not possible due to the limited storage space.

I tried different schemes in the past but have always been frustrated by the difficulty to keep files consistent over multiple storage devices (internal and external hard disk drives on the multiple computers). By consistent, I mean that those files that are intended to be present on multiple drives should be exactly the same and up-to-date with the latest version, while other files should be present only on a spacious drives.

It's important for me to keep a set of source codes, input data files, raw output files of simulation runs, analysis and plotting scripts, and output files of the analysis for each project in an accessible way, in order to keep myself accountable for my published results as well as to accelerate future research based on the past projects.

In the last few years, I have used git to version control my source codes and keep them synchronized over multiple computers. I also used unison to synchronize data files between my laptop, a USB hard disk drive, and a desktop computer, to some extent. I like both of these tools, and I'm wondering if I can make a more efficient work flow with more extensive use of them. I also use rsync to fetch and push files from one computer to another manually.

I have the following hypothetical directory tree as a collection of all of my projects:

```
projects/ (about a few TB)
  - projA/ (about a few 100 GB)
    + deploy/
    + dvlp/
      + stable/
        + .git/
        + source/
        + doc/
        + tests/
        + bin/
      + sandbox/
        + debug000
        + ..
        + debug999
    + jobs_v000_machineA/
    + jobs_v000_machineB/
    - jobs_v001_machineA/ (about 100 GB)
        + source/
        + doc/
        + tests/
        + bin/
        - job000/ (about 10 GB)
          - input.dat
          - input_moo.dat
          - out_foo000.dat
          - out_bar000.dat
          - ..
          + graph000/ (about 10 MB)
          + graph001/
        + job001/
        + ..
        + job099/ 
  - projB/
  ..
  - projQ/
```

but it's hypothetical at the moment because any of the storage drives doesn't completely mirror this entire tree. On one drive (an older USB Hard disk drive), the actual tree is

```
projects/ 
  - projA/
  - ..
  - projN/
```

while on another drive (an internal disk on a computing machine) it is like

```
projects/ 
  - projL/
  - ..
  - projQ/
    - deploy/
    - jobs_v001_machineA/
        + source/
        + doc/
        + tests/
        + bin/
      - job000/
          - input.dat
          - input_moo.dat
          - out_foo000.dat
          - ..
          - out_foo320.dat
      + job001/
```

Yet on another drive (an internal disk on the laptop), it is like

```
projects/ 
  - projL/
  - ..
  - projQ/
    - deploy/
    - dvlp/
      + stable/
      + sandbox/
    - jobs_v001_machineA/
        + source/
        + doc/
        + tests/
        + bin/
      - job000/
          - input.dat
          - input_moo.dat
          - out_foo000.dat
          - ..
          - out_foo320.dat
        + graph000/
        + graph001/
      - job001/
```

I can buy an external USB hard disk drive of a few TB capacity to store the entire `projects/` tree now. But, still I want to have an efficient and reliable way to partially synchronize an appropriate subtree of it with each computers.

I saw the following related questions, but they do not address exactly my concerns.

- [Archiving papers, simulation and experimental data, etc?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8359/12226)

  - This case does not involve a large data that doesn't fit in one of the computer.
- [Organizing data and files](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/52675/12226)

  - This post does not seem to be concerned about files being scattered over multiple computers.

I found the following tool, but it's an overkill for me.

- [Pegasus, a Workflow Management System for Science Automation](https://pegasus.isi.edu/wordpress/wp-content/papercite-data/pdf/deelman-fgcs-2015.pdf)

  - I will be spending more time to learn how to use the tool than writing codes.

I would appreciate your advices.

Comment: Have you considered [rsync](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rsync&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html)? And a much bigger internal harddrive sounds like a good investment.

Comment: BTW, this may be more on-topic on the software-recommendations stack.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should me migrated to software-rec.se

Comment: Also may be appropriate scicomp.stackexchange

Comment: @henning Yes, as I wrote, I am using rsync.

Comment: @norio Sorry, I missed that (your question is quite detailed). Why does rsync not solve your problem? Is it because you have to think about running it regularly, because you would like to sync the entire tree but only have space for a subtree, or because of something else?

Comment: @henning I doubt that there is a single software that automates the workflow. I want to know how other researchers make their day-to-day workflow, what they identified as essential requirements, and how they have addressed. That is to say, I want to get the know-how of how to combine several types of software effectively.

Comment: @henning A problem with rsync is that it's a one-way mirroring. If I change a file on two machines and run rsync, I lose one of them, for example. So, I always need to remember to not to work under some path on some machine. As another example, if I change a file on machineA and rsync machineB:file machineA:file by mistake, I lose the change. So, I always need to remember which machine has the latest version of each file before running rsync. This task takes up much mental energy.

Comment: Store the files on one powerful machine that has lots of disk space. Set up backups on that machine for disaster recovery. When you're working on another machine, instead of processing files locally, use a remote access tool such as TeamViewer or NoMachine to remote into your main machine and work with the data so the data always stays in one place. For source code, use git and set up a remote repository.

Comment: Isn't it a question for the superuser.SE? I'd use LLVM or something (ZFS?) to create a single tree over multiple drives.

Answer (score 1):

Use cloud storage.

There are several options out there. GitHub for source code. Microsoft OneDrive for office files. Amazon Web Services for databases or if you feel like setting up a more customized solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but this doesn't seem to solve the problem of files scattered all over. I want to know a systematic way that my laptop is sync with all of these cloud storage only for a necessary subtree.

Comment: OneDrive allows that.